# site is exposed to TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 enabled

Tags: .net, web-services, azure, azure-web-app-service, protocols

Under VAPT (testing) our site is enabled to TLS v1.0 and TLS v1.1.
Is there any way so that we can disable these protocols TLS v1.0 and TLS v1.1. ?
We have hosted this site (www.mysite.com) in Azure app service.
It is based on .net platform.
When we tested this domain at
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

It shows following results
[image]

Hope this information is sufficient
Regards
Kunal

Comment: There should be an "SSL settings" section for your App Service in the Azure portal where you can configure this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could go to your Azure App Service blade -> **SSL settings** ->set **Minimum TLS Version** to **1.2**. You could refer to the screenshot.

[image]

**Note**: If you find the v1.0 is remain enabled after changing the setting, just like the screenshot, this is caused by Azure itself. You could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/04/17/app-service-and-functions-hosted-apps-can-now-update-tls-versions/), the App Service Team has replied to this issue. I think it will work fine soon.

[image]

> **Christiaan Arnoldus**: I’ve configured an app to require TLS 1.2, but now SSLLabs reports TLS 1.2 and 1.0 as supported and 1.1 as unsupported. Any idea why 1.0 is still listed as acceptable?
>
> **Oded Dvoskin**: This will updated to reflect the change in the next couple weeks. Expected first week of May.
>
> UPDATE: This will only launch toward the middle of May, due to the discovery of a breaking change this has the potential of causing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let us wait for disabling tlsv1.0 till middle of May.